# Add a label to result set based on criteria

Tags: mysql, database

Guys i have an employee table and i want to list people having salary greater than 70000 as `greater` and people having salary less than 70000 as `lower`.

[image: Table Photo]

So far i was only able to do this by writing 2 queries for greater and lower.

I want to write a single query to do this job.

Comment: `UNION ALL` the two queries if you can write them

Comment: *Combining Mysql query to list people having salary greater than 70000 and people having salary less than 70000* - this is the same as "list all people except ones who have salary strictly equal to 70000". Edit your subj and make it more adequate..

Answer (score -1):

You can use a [`case`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) for this.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SALARAY > 70000 THEN 'Greater' ELSE 'Lower' end as is_greater, othercolumns
FROM ...
```